# How to test NodeJS application using Mocha, Grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, gruntjs, bdd

Maybe someone met any npm module/tutorial/guide/article about "how to test nodejs application using mocha, gruntjs?" Would be glad to any suggestions.

Comment: kind of repetition… But shouldn't javascript- tests/code be made in a way that it is possible to test/run it, as independently as possible from the context it should work within? For me it sounds like the problem of testing javascript code, that relies on DOM objects, transferred to node.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend the following (it worked for me):

1. Install Grunt and get your first sample grunt task running based on [the Grunt documentation](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)
2. Use [this grunt task](https://github.com/pghalliday/grunt-mocha-test) to get server-side Grunt running Mocha tests for you, and [this one](https://github.com/kmiyashiro/grunt-mocha) for client-side tests. From the command line, you can just run `$ grunt` to watch the results pop up.
3. At this point, you can check out [Mocha interfaces](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#interfaces) for samples of how your tests can look. Note that there's also [should.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js), if you're big on rSpec-style tests. Once you've settled on an interface, more Googling/StackOverflowing is the best way to proceed (e.g. Google "Mocha should.js examples").

Comment: Thanks for this solution, nice way to just get a simple grunt driven task running with mocha. Prefer Chai though.